# Solving two-dimensional recurrence relation $a_{i,j} = (j-1)a_{i-1,j} + a_{i-1,j+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I've been given this problem. Does anyone know how to approach the following two dimensional recurrence relation?

> For all $i, j ≥ 2,$
>
> $a_{i,j} = (j-1)a_{i-1,j} + a_{i-1,j+1}$
>
> where $ a_{1,k} = k$

I've been trying to find a general solution for it for quite a while.

Of course

> $a_{2,k} = (k-1)a_{1,k} + a_{1,k+1} = (k-1)k + (k + 1) = k^2 + 1$
> $a_{3,k} = (k-1)a_{2,k} + a_{2,k+1} = (k-1)(k^2 + 1) + ((k+1)^2 + 1) = k^3 + 3k + 1$

But is there a way to generalize $a_{i,j}$ for given $i$?

Comment: So you have got as far as $a_{2,k}=k^2+1$ ? ... So write it into your question !

Comment: You can try generating functions as shown in [Solving two-dimensional recurrence relation $a_{i,\ j}\ =\ a_{i,\ j-1}\ +\ a_{i-1,\ j-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065067/solving-two-dimensional-recurrence-relation-a-i-j-a-i-j-1-a-i/2065193#2065193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the $r$-Bell numbers, which appear as [OEIS sequence A108087](https://oeis.org/A108087).