# Solving recurrence relation with 2 variables

Tags: recurrence-relations

If I have a recurrence relation like $$T(n,k)=\frac{T(n-1,k)+T(n,k-1)}{2}$$ with initial values $\forall n \quad T(n,0)=T_0$ and $\forall k \quad T(0,k)=0$. How can I solve it? By the way this came up when I was solving a physics problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JeanMarie's answer points out we also need $T_{0,\,p}$ for $p>0$. My guess is you want these to be $0$. But whether I'm right or not, your question should address this boundary too.

Comment: $T_{0,p}$ is $0$ @J.G.

Comment: @spitfire In that case, you might want to work out a recursion relation in a sequence $p_n$ of polynomial functions of $k$ satisfying $T(n,\,k)=T_0p_n(k)/2^{n+k-1}$.

Comment: @J.G. but what is $p_n$? Polynomial functions of $k$? Sorry but I didn't get what are these. I'm not a mathematician I'm a physicist

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited my question and there's no doubts  I think

Comment: @spitfire:  Here's a different approach...  There's a simple book that explains a lot about these types of recurrence relations called "generatingfunctionology".  You can get a free copy of the book at https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html  In particular, check out section 1.4, which expains two-term functions.  I hope that this may help.

Comment: Follow approach from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065067/solving-two-dimensional-recurrence-relation-a-i-j-a-i-j-1-a-i/2065193#2065193. Also warning, you will need to get your definitions straight. As currently written, it is unclear what is $T(0,0)$, is it $T_0$ or $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graphical representation of your recurrence relationship :

[image]

(which, now that you have settled correctly your initial data, isn't compulsory, but is interesting by itself because it shows its similarity with the **¨Pascal's triangle"** (see below).

Some numerical computations on the first values of $T_{n,k}$ in the case of $T_0=1$ give the following first numerical results with denominators $2^{n+k-1}$.

(please note the diagonal values equal to $1/2$) :

[image]

Out of this array, we can build a simplified one by turning it $135°$clockwise in the "Pascal's triangle' manner and keeping **only the numerators** where the right diagonal, instead of being filled by "ones", is filled by successive powers of $2$ :

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
&&&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&\color{blue}{1}&&\color{red}{2}&&&&&\\
&&&\color{blue}{1}&&3&&\color{red}{4}&&&&&&&&\\
&&\color{blue}{1}&&4&&7&&\color{red}{8}&&&\\
&\color{blue}{1}&&5&&11&&15&&\color{red}{16}&&&\\
\color{blue}{1}&&6&&16&&26&&31&&\color{red}{32}
\end{array}\tag{1}$$

We have simplified the problem because in this way only integers are managed, and (thanks to an indication by the OP) this is known in the litterature under the name ["Bernoulli triangle"](http://oeis.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_triangle) yielding the explicit formula for the coefficients in the previous "Pascal's like" array (1) (it is why we write $T'$ instead of $T$):

$$\displaystyle T'_{n,k}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum _{p=0}^{k}{\binom {n}{p}} \ \ \text{for} \ \ k=0,1,\cdots n$$

Comment: I'm sorry for not writing it in my question @Jean Marie

Comment: I'm sorry but this wasn't clear to me. So why do we need that graphical represantation? how can we solve  the recurrence relation?

Comment: I get what you wrote there, but how can I find $T_{n,k}$ in terms of  $n$,$k$,$T_0$.I've searched about wave propagation with damping but i didn't find anything. So can you explain more? by the way what you mean numerical value for $T_{0,q}$ they are all zeros

Comment: And all the $T(n,0)$ is not equal to $0$ it's equal to $T_0$

Comment: I have improved the approach by reducing the issue to a pure integer question (In the case $T_0=1$). But I still doubt there is a closed form expression for the general term.

Comment: I find solution to this problem : https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/719928959256625232/724081817828851758/potd_193.pdf

Comment: Therfore the keyword for what I had found is "Bernoulli triangle", with a formula for $T_{n,k}$ that still contains a "\Sigma"..