# closed-form solution to a recursive function

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

My question is about this problem I made up:
'I have a height of unit length, and m glass balls. Dropping a ball higher than some unknown height, h, always breaks them, and dropping a ball lower never breaks them, and h is between 0 and 1. Given n drops, what is the smallest interval size I can guarantee for h?'

Note that a ball can be re-used if it isn't broken, and I am dropping balls *1 at a time*. Whatever happens to the balls, I can only drop a maximum total of n times.

Let s(n,m) be the smallest interval size I can guarantee for h with n drops and m balls, with n and m being non-negative integers - **is there a closed-form formula for s(n,m)?**

I guessed s(n,n) = $\frac{1}{2^n}$ , and s(n,1) = $\frac{1}{n+1}$. I then, independently to the previous guesses, found the recursive definition s(n,m) = $\frac{s(n-1,m)s(n-1,m-1)}{s(n-1,m)+s(n-1,m-1)}$. Using induction and the recursive definition, I proved the previous two guesses. However, I don't know where to go from this, and couldn't find this problem anywhere else online. By closed-form, I mean including standard operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, and common functions such as logarithms and trigonometric functions, and I don't mind a piecewise definition for s(n,m).

Comment: Note that your recurrence is
$$
\frac{1}{s \left( n,m \right)}= \frac{1}{s \left( n-1,m-1
 \right)}+ \frac{1}{s \left( n-1,m \right)} .
$$
So why not consider instead 
$t(n,m) = \frac{1}{s(n,m)}$ and try for a closed form of that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22egg+drop%22

Comment: Your recurrence is missing some initial conditions, for example try calculating $s(1,2)$.

Comment: any case with m equal to or bigger than n is easy, as in that case, s(n, m) = s(n, n)

Comment: @RobPratt, that problem is about 2 eggs, and about dropping from discrete floors, so it's a bit different.

Comment: @umair It is easy, but that is an information that should go into the post. Then you can  start solving such recurrence once it is correctly defined.

Comment: Again, good catch.  Again, I misinterpreted the problem.  I thought that each ball could be dropped $(n)$ times.  Instead, your intent is that the maximum number of drops, for all balls combined is $(n)$.  So, again, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going purely from the recurrence relation, as noted in comments setting $t(n,m) = \frac{1}{s(n,m)}$ it becomes $$t(n,m)=t(n-1,m-1)+t(n-1,m)$$
with initial conditions $t(n,m)=2^n$ for $n \leq m$ and $t(n,1)=n+1$. The recurrence reminds the [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), which suggests that some finite sum of binomial coefficients could be the solution. This and the initial conditions motivates
$$
t(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}.
$$
To prove this simply verify the recurrence relation and the initial conditions.

Alternatively you could use bivariate generating function $f(x,y)=\sum t(n,m)x^ny^m$ to derive the same result (see for example [Solving two-dimensional recurrence relation $a_{i,\ j}\ =\ a_{i,\ j-1}\ +\ a_{i-1,\ j-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065067) for a similar result).